# storing an array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm new to mongodb 3.2 and I'm wondering what the accepted method to store an array.

I have a safe words array that just contains... words.

I want to store it in mongodb for a fast comparison of a queried word.

should I just create a document, and add to it objects with one property called 'word' that contains a word?

should I create a document with one object that contains the property words with an array of words?

maybe something else?

any ideas?

Comment: i think this is not a mongodb question, but more of a design question.

Comment: The trouble with placing all words in an array in one document is that, in mongodb, one document's size is limited to 16mb. A collection, however does not have any theoretical limit on documents in it. You can explore other options such as Redis and Prefix-Trie etc, if word matching performance is of importance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB supports dynamic schema i.e  The documents stored in the database can have varying sets of fields, with different types for each field

Following example demonstrates storing an array in MongoDB document

{
  _id : ObjectId("56bc838924f5ca3e0d3c9871"),
  "tags":["mongodb","NoSQL"]
}

In above example tags is an array field which stores all tags